# Symfony2 Firewall not preventing access

Tags: php, symfony

I think I don't fully understand the concept of firewall and access control of symfony but here's my understanding.

I have FOSUserBundle installed and configured properly.

I created some roles:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_COACH:           [ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_EDITOR:          [ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_PREMIUM_COACH :  [ROLE_USER, ROLE_COACH]
    ROLE_ADMIN:           [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_COACH, ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_PREMIUM_COACH]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:     [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

I want to prevent people from accessing the url /dashboard if they are not logged in, therefore if they don't have the role ROLE_USER.

Here's my firewall:

```
firewalls:
    # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
    admin:
        pattern:      /admin(.*)
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /admin/login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /admin/login_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:
            path:           /admin/logout
        anonymous:    true
    # -> end custom configuration

    # defaut login area for standard users
    main:
        pattern:      .*
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider:  form.csrf_provider
            login_path:     /login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /login_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

Here's what I added under access_control:

```
    - { path: ^/dashboard, role: [ROLE_USER]}
    - { path: ^/dashboard/blog, role: [ROLE_EDITOR]}
```

I can access the page /dashboard even if I'm not connected and I don't want that possible. What am I getting wrong ?

Comment: Anonymous: true is the culprit

Comment: What should I do then ? isn't suppose to be overwritten when you specify that a route must have a role ?

Comment: Try making another firewall just for your dashboard.

Comment: This sound weird to me ... Could you paste some log aftare the offending action  ??

Comment: @DonCallisto what log exactly do you want ? I can access the page and that's my problem, I don't want to access /dashboard if I'm not logged in

Comment: I would love to know what is going here, so if you paste logs (`/app/logs/dev.log`) I can figure out where it fails :)

Comment: here's my log : http://pastebin.com/ijKNhBh2 if you see /OSC/dashboard, it represents /dashboard in my question, I changed it to /dashboard in my question since I thought that asking my question with only /dashboard was more clear.

Comment: @DonCallisto any updates on why this is an issue ?

Comment: @CoachNono: If you don't paste any log, as I said, I can't stand why your firewall and acl do not works properly.

Comment: @DonCallisto I pasted it, that's why I re asked you.here's again: http://pastebin.com/ijKNhBh2

Comment: @CoachNono:sorry, didn't noticed that yet... Ok, can I see `osc_dashboard_homepage` route (ps.: if you have a prefix that point to another .yml with routes, please include it)

Comment: @DonCallisto http://pastebin.com/Q1gvqqah

Comment: @CoachNono: only for a better understanding, so your ACL is path: `- ^/OSC/dashboard, role: [ROLE_USER]}` and `- { path: ^/dashboard/blog, role: [ROLE_EDITOR]}` ??

Comment: @DonCallisto exactly, I'm wondering also if I create another firewall such as main and setting anonymous to false would solve the problem, I'll test that to see

Comment: @DonCallisto Here's what I tried: http://pastebin.com/FvfPCtnP now, it prevents me from accessing /OSC/dashboard. However, even if I log in (with the proper ROLE), then I type the url /OSC/dashboard, it redirects me to the login screen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From that [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FvfPCtnP)

```
- { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

this line is what cause your issue. This tells to symfony2 security system that every user can access everything (this is the "very first rule" if you ignore the FOS ones) and so, when this is satified, no other controll will be done (as `- { path: ^/OSC/dashboard, role: ROLE_USER}` came after)

Possibile solutions:

1) Place that line at the bottom of your acl.

**PRO**: your application will work
**CONS**: if you don't properly set all ACL, you'll run into "security" issues or some unauthorized users could access pages that, into your logic, they have not to access.

2) Remove that line at all

**PRO**: your application will not suffer from security issues and unauthorized access
**CONS**: you have to set all route explicitly and properly, but this is pretty "natural" if you want to build a strong application

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're getting through is because there isn't a firewall for `/dashboard`, but (assuming you're trying to setup `SonataAdminBundle`) that's not what you're supposed to have in `access_control`

Here's how mine looks for `Sonata`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login-check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

    - { path: ^/.*, role: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }
```

Your firewall definition is fine otherwise.

If you're trying to configure you're own custom dashboard, then you need to define another firewall entry, very similar to the `admin` firewall.

**EDIT**:

Try changing pattern to: `^/.*`

If you want to block just `/OSC` then: `/OSC(.*)`

Comment: There is a firewall for /dashboard and is called "main" in the OP question